# Generating recovery codes for a 2FA implementation

Tags: node.js, authentication, two-factor-authentication

I have implemented a 2FA auth on a project and it works fine with different authenticators, which is great.

Now I am developing the recovery codes part of the flow, that are provided by services implementing 2FA such as Google and GitHub.

I'm generating them with a certain length and an arbitrary amount of them. My doubt is how would be the correct way to store them?

- Should I hash them? I asked this because it would be a simple answer YES, it's more secure but I see that pages like Github allows you to show the codes after you activate 2FA, so I would need a different type of hashing.
- What about the secret key (TOTP 2FA), should it be hashed as well?

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1):

You should hash the recovery codes but not the secret. If you hash the secret you have no way of recovering it when checking the TOTP code.

According to [RFC6238](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6238):

- There MUST be a unique secret (key) for each prover.
- The keys SHOULD be randomly generated or derived using key derivation algorithms.
- The keys MAY be stored in a tamper-resistant device and SHOULD be protected against unauthorized access and usage.

You could store the TOTP secret encrypted, and decrypt it when the user attempts to verify the code, but for obvious reasons, you can't store it hashed.